# AngularJs ServiceMethod with more parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

in my controller I have this method:
       ..............

```
     angular.extend($scope.criteria, $scope.items);  
            angular.extend($scope.criteriaList, $scope.itemsUpdate); 
            console.log('scope %O: ' ,$scope.criteria);
            console.log('scope_ %O: ' ,$scope.criteriaList);
            updateList.getItems($scope.criteria,$scope.criteriaList, function(data){
                 });


and in my service I did this:

      amServices.factory('updateList', [ function() {               
      var updateList= new function(){};
    updateList.getItems = function( items, itemsUpdate,callback){
        console.log('itemsUpdat e%O ' , itemsUpdate);

                  callback(itemsList);   

}

return updateList 
             });
```

But I am not able to print the result..

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your var updateList should be an array of functions not a function itself. Like below

```
amServices.factory('updateList', [ function() {               
      var updateList= {};
    updateList.getItems = function( items, itemsUpdate,callback){
        console.log('itemsUpdat e%O ' , itemsUpdate);

                  callback(itemsList);   

}

return updateList 
             });
```

Comment: @Opeyemi: I have the same problem..... console.log('itemsUpdat e%O ' , itemsUpdate); doesn't work....It is correct to pass the parameters from controllers to service method in the way?